# How to get the Quick Help back in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode

After I upgraded to Xcode 10 the Quick Help information only provide declaration of the selected class or structure.

Is there a setting somewhere that I can make it same as what it was in Xcode 9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading where the function signature is the only thing showing when doing an option click. 
Quick Help reappeared when I deleted everything inside *`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`* as well as in  *`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`*. You need to quit xcode first btw. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry. How to get into ~/Library/ folder? Thanks

Comment: I am having frozen black simulators after upgrading to Xcode 10. Anything could be related to other derivedData or cache?

Comment: hi paul,. black simulators? i haven't run into this problem yet. but if u happen to fix it, please do share. thanks heaps ;)

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded Xcode 9.4.1. Expanded the folder. But where is your ~/Library folder? I want to do some comparisons

Comment: I found it. But the problem isn't in the Xcode folder. It is in /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework. I cannot find this folder in Xcode package

Comment: Worked great for me.