# Xcode 10.1 (10B61) not showing QuickHelp for imported libraries

Tags: xcode, xcode10.1

I am taking a course in Udemy for iOS development in which they are showing that we can `⌥` (ALT / command) + click to get a Quick Help reference for the imported library. It seems in the course that they are using a previous version of Xcode such as 9.X

[image]

However if I do the same I get this:

[image]

A message saying `No Quick Help`. If I click on the `Search Documentation` button below I can effectively see the documentation of it, but not as shown in the video.

I've already tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52424626/2180785), also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40583830/2180785) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39843226/2180785) without success.

As I'm not familiar with the previous versions or changes made, is this something made intentionally by Apple? Or is this a bug that can be fixed and how?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, I'm using:

`MacBook Pro 13 inch, 2016 with Touch Bar`

Running on `macOS Mojave 10.14.1`

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is true. I'm a little surprised to hear that it was ever possible to get Quick Help on the name of a framework, but you certainly can't get it now. If you can demonstrate a use case where this feature is valuable, please do file a bug report with Apple.

As you also rightly say, the alternative way to do this is simply to go to the documentation page and type CoreLocation into the search field, or select the term CoreLocation and choose Help > Search Documentation For Selected Text. You will (eventually) reach the same text that was being displayed in the Quick Help in the screen shot you showed.

If the point of your remarks is to point out that the integration between code and the documentation has degraded with recent successive versions of Xcode, I think most of us would assent to that.

Comment: I see, so it might be a bug in Xcode, I think I'll reach out to them. And well, my remarks were more related to see if there was a solution to this rather than showing a poor integration (which as per your comment I see it's the case). Apple does a good job with UX for final users but it's doing it the wrong way for developers I guess.

Comment: I don't know that it's a bug per se. Apple keeps shedding features, and some of them were good. What you want is for them to bring back this one. :) You will have to plead with them. The more people complain, the more likely they are to listen.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'll let the question open in case someone comes with a workaround

Comment: Sure no problem.